# TCP Client Accepting Objects

Tags: java, tcpclient

I am writing a java program that needs to continuously accept serialized objects throughout the run of the application.  The objects are sent by a server as requested by the user.

My main application initializes the tcp client (extends thread) in its run method, but I am trying to read objects from the line from a function.

Pseudocode follows:

```
*tcp client extends thread

*global vars: ip, port, socket, oi stream, oo stream, object reference

*run()
      make connection

*getObject()
      object reference = (object).readobject()
      return object
```

My main application calls `client.getObject()` in an update loop.  there may or not be an object waiting.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Please discuss number of clients; connection life-cycle; connection semantics (e.g. session based or not); and average payload size.  Finally (important) address maximizing which of latency or throughput is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do "classic" server behavior or non-blocking IO?

If it's the former, I'd recommend a blocking queue on the server to accept incoming requests and a pool of threads to process them.  Have the server assign a thread to process the request when it comes in until the thread pool is exhausted; queue up requests until threads are freed up and returned to the pool.

Non-blocking IO is another matter entirely.  Look at how [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) are designed and implemented for that.

I would never have a class extend `Thread` - it's unlikely that you'll add significant new behavior.  Implement `Runnable` instead and give it to a `Thread` instance to run.

Comment: i have been reading that runnable is the better way to go, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @duffymo: how could you possibly proscribe all that without even a tiniest bit of input as to what is the usage scenario, number of clients, connection durability, etc?  And throwing NIO at Java network newbees is probably going to cause far more confusion that insight.  [2c/gentle tone]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest your run() method reads all the objects and adds them to a queue.
getOject() takes the next object from the queue.
You can also have a `int queueLength()` to check how any are waiting.